# Civisualize not reporting Gender

Tags: civisualize

Civisualize seems to be reporting on most things, however the Gender report shows a green circle with 99% but no breakdown of gender even though we have male and female members. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by reinstalling the module